# Fabric set('src',url) not working but setSrc(url) working

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

So I have these two lines of code-

1. `canvas.item(0).set('src',url); canvas.renderAll();`
2. `canvas.item(0).setSrc(url); canvas.renderAll();`

So there's an existing canvas with an image loaded at layer 0. so when I am using Solution1, it should change the image. but it's not reflecting. When I try `console.log(canvas.item(0))`, it shows `url` set to the `src` attribute in the `object array`, but it never reflects. Then when I use Solution2, it works. But even then it's buggy. I have to run Solution2 twice & then it shows. What's the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [image#setSrc](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#setSrc) to change the source of image object, which accepts a callback, there render the canvas. So you no need to call `setSrc` again.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('editorCanvas', {
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  width: 300,
  height: 300
});
var imageObject;
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://picsum.photos/200/200', function(img) {
  img.set({width:200,height:200,scaleX:1,scaleY:1})
  imageObject = img;
  canvas.add(img);
},{crossOrigin:'annonymous'});
var i=0;

function changeSrc(){
  var url = 'https://picsum.photos/200/200?random='+ ++i;
  imageObject.setSrc(url,function(){
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  },{crossOrigin:'annonymous'})
}
```

```css
canvas{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.7.0/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick='changeSrc()'>changeSrc</button>
<button onclick='addFilter()'>addFilter</button><br>
<canvas id="editorCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks man.. the callback was the key.. shifted `canvas.renderAll()` inside the callback

Comment: Since in the "DEMO", both the image URLs are same except random factor, the code actually will not reflect the image change on the canvas, until you add `img.set('dirty', true);` inside callback.